# How to align text automatically inside a tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox, text

```
\put(160,-240){
\centering
Bottom Mid}
\put(100,-125){
User möchte Möglichkeit haben einen Modus mit\newline Schachuhr auswählen zu können, um ein professionelleres Erlebnis zu haben  }
```

This code is inside a huge tcolorbox. Now as you see I want to produce a new line but that does not work.
\centering also does not seem to work in such a environment.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "Now as you see I want to produce a new line but that does not work". I fail to see anything in this code fragment. There is no `tcolorbox`, let alone a minimal working example. (And `\put` in a `tcolorbox`, really?)

Comment: the put worked hahah

Comment: Sure, it "works". `\put(100,-125){\begin{tabular}[t]{l}
User möchte Möglichkeit haben einen Modus mit\\ Schachuhr auswählen zu können, um ein professionelleres Erlebnis zu haben\end{tabular}  }` will also "work". It's just not the optimal way to do it.